# LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial failing on local extern

Tags: llvm, extern

I am working through the [LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl05.html). Everything is working fine except for *local* externs (as opposed to things like the math functions).

```
[c34n10 kaleidoscope] ./toy
ready> extern sin(x); sin(1);
ready> Read extern:
declare double @sin(double)

ready> ready> Evaluated to 0.841471
ready> extern putchard(x); putchard(120);
ready> Read extern:
declare double @putchard(double)

ready> ready> Failure value returned from cantFail wrapped call
UNREACHABLE executed at /gpfs/loomis/project/fas/manohar/emb99/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Error.h:732!
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`putchard` is declared in my code, per the tutorial, as

```
/// putchard - putchar that takes a double and returns 0.
extern "C" DLLEXPORT double putchard(double X) {
  fputc((char)X, stderr);
  return 0;
}
```

Other posts online suggest that this issue could be caused by not compiling with `-rdynamic`, but I am.

The actual error is occuring with the following code

```
auto ExprSymbol = TheJIT->findSymbol("__anon_expr");
assert(ExprSymbol && "Function not found");

// cast to double-returning function
double (*FP)() = (double (*)())(intptr_t)cantFail(ExprSymbol.getAddress());
fprintf(stderr, "Evaluated to %f\n", FP());
```

and some investigation with GDB reveals that the `hasError` flag of `ExprSymbol.getAddress()` is true, which is why the `cantFail` is failing. As to why that flag is set, I'm at a loss.

It appears not to be an issue with the function itself: from within GDB, I can successfully run `call putchard(120)`, so the symbol definitely exists in the executable.

Finally, my makefile looks like

```
LIBS=core orcjit native analysis executionengine instcombine object runtimedyld scalaropts support
FLAGS=`llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs $(LIBS)`

%: %.cpp
        clang++ -v -g3 -O0 $^ -o $@ $(FLAGS) -rdynamic
```

Comment: Hi baum, I'm also getting the same error when compiling with -Wl,--export-dynamic as mentioned in the tutorial. Did you find a solution for this? And also in the tutorial it is mentioned as mcjit not as orcjit, how did you find the correct lib?

Comment: Hello, fellow traveler. No solution yet. Also, I'm compiling verbose (`-v`) and `--export-dynamic` is already being included (possibly `-rdynamic` is doing that). As for mcjit/orcjit, I was having compilation issues and realized that I was using `orc` classes, but never including those libraries. I've contacted the llvm-dev listserv; I'll update here if anyone writes back.

Comment: Thanks, I too saw the update on logging error messages for your mail in llvm-dev lists. I too got the same error "Symbols not found {printd}".

Comment: This looks like it's related. I'm also failing the test case given: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/llvm-dev/5XbVMI75OSA

Comment: @PreeJackie did you install LLVM 8 via SVN? I am trying the most recent stable release (7.0.0)

Comment: Does not work on stable release 7.0.1.

Comment: No, I installed via git. I'm using llvm 8.0.0

Comment: So, no solutions for it ?

Comment: 6.0.1 works... no solutions yet for 7 or 8, unfortunately.

Comment: oh, hope someone replies:)

Comment: I think LLVM 9 fixes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into exactly the same issue in LLVM 8.

The problem is the symbol resolver doesn't try to find the requested symbol in local process's address, and an `Expected<T>` requires mandatory checking for errors.

I changed `KaleidoscopeJIT.h` a bit to get over it.

Replace the KaleidoscopeJIT's constructor with this one:

```
KaleidoscopeJIT()
      : Resolver(createLegacyLookupResolver(
            ES,
            [this](const std::string &Name) {
              auto symbol = ObjectLayer.findSymbol(Name, true);
              if (!symbol)
              {
                if (auto SymAddr = RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(Name))
                  return JITSymbol(SymAddr, JITSymbolFlags::Exported);
              }
              return symbol;
            },
            [](Error Err) { cantFail(std::move(Err), "lookupFlags failed"); })),
        TM(EngineBuilder().selectTarget()), DL(TM->createDataLayout()),
        ObjectLayer(ES,
                    [this](VModuleKey) {
                      return ObjLayerT::Resources{
                          std::make_shared<SectionMemoryManager>(), Resolver};
                    }),
        CompileLayer(ObjectLayer, SimpleCompiler(*TM)) {
    llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::LoadLibraryPermanently(nullptr);
  }
```

The only change is, if no symbol is found after calling `ObjectLayer.findSymbol()`, it will turn to `RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess()` to find and create the JITSymbol object.

Comment: No longer working on this project, so cannot confirm results. Accepting anyway hoping this can be of use to others in the future.